# Android contact lists - How to seperate my app created contacts from the rest of the phone?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

one of my app features requires adding & removing contacts, generally speaking it is used for a TEMPORARY fix.

I don't want to manage the phones contacts and most importantly don't want to delete other contacts by mistake.

**How can I create a contact list to store them JUST for the use of my app when I query?**

-- EDIT

Would also appreciate any open source libs for this purpose, I couldn't find any that used only Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, don't use Android `ContactsContract` APIs, instead create and manage your own contacts in your own internal DB.
You can create a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` to help you get started with an `SQLite` internal Database.

If you do need to use `ContactsContract`'s APIs, you should put all your app's `RawContacts` with your app's `ACCOUNT_NAME` / `ACCOUNT_TYPE` pair so other apps can know that RawContact is related to your app, and you can then make your account hidden, so suggest to contacts app not to display those contacts.
However, you can't force that suggestion, and other apps or users can make your contacts visible.

See: http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/ and http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter for details on Android accounts with `ACCOUNT_NAME` / `ACCOUNT_TYPE` using a `SyncAdapter`.